# Knockout options binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/user/jsjs/fiddles/

I am having trouble binding the following `<select>` element using Knockout.js options binding to a nested viewModel.  Am I missing something?  I tried userFSR().facilityOptions, mainView().userFSR().facilityoptions, and userFSR.facility().  All of them raised javascript runtime error. The only one didn't raise runtime error is in the html fragment below, but the dropdown is empty after it is rendered. Thank you for your help.

```
        <div id="userFSR">
            <select id="selectFacility" 
                data-bind="options: userFSR.facilityOptions,
                    selectedOptions: userFSR.facilitySelected,
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose facility...',
                    optionsValue: function(item){ 
                        return item.facility_ID
                    },
                    optionsText: function(item){ 
                        return item.facility_name
                    }">
            </select>
        </div>
```

The following is the viewModel content after doing ko.toJSON(self, null, 2) like this

```
self.toggleVM = function () {
    if ($("pre#viewModel").css("display").search("none") != -1) {
        $("pre#viewModel").html(ko.toJSON(self, null, 2));
        $("pre#viewModel").show();
    }
    else
        $("pre#viewModel").hide();
}
```

viewModel Outpout:

```
   {
      "btnCancelValue": "Cancel",
      "userBeforeEdit": {
            /* omitted */
      },
      "users": [
        {
            /* omitted */
        },
        {
            /* omitted */
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        /* omitted */
      },
      "operationStatus": "omitted",
      "currentIni": "Q",
      "initials": [
        {
          "initial": "+",
          "apiUrl": "/* omitted */"
        },
        {
          /* omitted */
        }
      ],
      "userFSR": {
        "facilityOptions": [
          {
            "$id": "1",
            "s_FacilityService": [],
            "facility_ID": 531,
            "facility_name": "City 1, State 1",
            "Facility_Code": null
          },
          {
            "$id": "2",
            "s_FacilityService": [],
            "facility_ID": 648,
            "facility_name": "City 2, State 2",
            "Facility_Code": null
          },
          {
            "$id": "3",
            "s_FacilityService": [],
            "facility_ID": 663,
            "facility_name": "City 3, State 3",
            "Facility_Code": null
          }
        ],
        "serviceOptions": [],
        "roleOptions": [],
        "roleSelected": [],
        "FsrCollection": []
      },
      "userPrefFSR": {
        "fsrPrefCollection": []
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `facilitySelected` in your view model. Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: If your `userFSR` is a `ko.observable` then you need to write `data-bind="options: userFSR().facilityOptions,
                    selectedOptions: userFSR().facilitySelected,`

Comment: Then create a JSFiddle which demonstrates your problem, because your code in your post is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MVnjR/

Comment: @nemesv, I post my code in http://jsfiddle.net/user/jsjs/fiddles/.  I am new to JSFIDDLE, so not sure how to put everything together there.

Comment: well, after several weeks of research and asking around, I gave up the use of nested view models.  I merged all variables and methods in the nested view models back into the main view model.  Having a huge model is not my cup of tea. This made me think that the Knockout.js is not good for modular and reuseable programming.  It may be capable of doing it, but it doesn't worth the amount of effort. The API documentation certainly is insufficient. I am moving on something else, Angular perhaps.